# Writing data to a zip archive in Python

Tags: python, zip, php-ziparchive, openpyxl

I've been told in the past that there is simply no easy way to write a string a zip file. It's okay to READ from a zip archive, but if you want to write to a zip file, the best option is to extract it, make the changes, and then zip it back up again. However, the library I am using (openpyxl) accomplishes the feat of writing to a zip file without any extraction. This package uses the writestr() function in the python ZipFile library to make changes. Can someone explain to me how exactly this is possible? I know it has something to do with writing bytes but I can't fine a good explanation.

I'm aware of the vagueness of this question, but that's a circumstance of my lack of knowledge on the topic.

Comment: you may want to take a look to python "tar" module

Comment: @DamiánMontenegro OP didn't ask for a lib, he asked how his library is probably doing it.

Answer (score 1):

openpyxl does not modify the files in place because you **can't** do this with zipfiles. You **must** extract, modify and archive. We just hide this process in the library.

Comment: How, exactly? I've been pouring over the source code, since I'm trying to adapt the process to .docx files and eventually to all Microsoft Office applications. I just can't seem to find the module/function that "does the work"